# What kind of Map does a Scala Iterable's "toMap" method return?

Tags: scala

A [Scala Iterable](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/Iterable.html) has a `toMap` method, which returns a Map. What is this map backed by? What are its performance characteristics?

Is there any way to specify that `toMap` should return a `HashMap`?

Comment: Knowing Scala it uses a `CanBuildFrom` implicit and what kind of map you get depends on what kind of map builders you have in scope which depends on what you import.

Comment: See [performance characteristics](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_40.html) of Scala collections.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It returns an `immutable.HashMap`, which is actually an [immutable hash array mapped trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_array_mapped_trie). This data structure is essentially a hybrid between a multilevel hashtable and a trie. The worst-case complexity of a hash array mapped trie is `O(log n)` for all operations, although with a very low constant factor - hash array mapped tries are very shallow, and typically have only a few indirections. You can read more about the performance characteristics [here](http://lampwww.epfl.ch/papers/idealhashtrees.pdf) or run a couple of microbencharks. The performance is acceptable in most cases.

The `toMap` always returns a hash trie. If you want a mutable hash table, then do this:

```
import collection._
mutable.HashMap() ++= xs
```

instead of:

```
xs.toMap
```

Comment: Is this a guarantee of the language or just the way it happens to be implemented now?

Comment: If it were a guarantee of the language, then it would be part of the contract. `toMap` would be declared to return `immutable.HashMap`. Since it is not part of the contract, we can assume that the creators of the Scala language will make sure to return the best general-purpose map implementation available in the standard library. In case anything better than `immutable.HashMap` comes around, they might change what is returned by `toMap`.

Comment: @Malvolio - it's just the way it's implemented now. Parallel collections, for example, will return a parallel.immutable.HashMap.

Comment: I looked at the code in scala.collection.* and think that `toMap` is `O(n^2)` - the map built from the list is immutable, and a new map object must cloned from the previous one each time an element is added. Some microbenchmarks support this: for a map with 5000 elements, Scala is 8 times slower than a fast Java implementation, for 500,000 elements, Scala is 20 times slower.

Comment: Adding an element to an immutable map is not `O(n)`, so `toMap` is not quadratic. And microbenchmarks would be much slower for 500k elements if that were the case.

Comment: its a bummer that toMap doesn't preserve order if the map toMap is performed on is one that preserves order (like a linkedhashmap or immutable ListMap). There really isn't a good way to convert a mutable LinkedHashMap to a immutable form (other than to hide its implementation as a scala.collection.Map. But then you have to deal with the issue that scala.collection.Map isn't the Predef Map (scala.collection.immutable.Map is). {facepalm} #GoodGrief

Comment: The solution is to add an overload for `toMap`, which is similar to the `to` combinator, but works for `Map`s, which expect 2 type parameters. This would allow you to specify the type of the target map, so you could preserve order. I suggest you submit a patch for this to scala-lang.